# how to preserve newline character in a string after converting to bytes?

Tags: java, string, stream, byte, arrays

```
String str[] = {"1000458551||A210171046D86F9F6EE21B66FE9B1441E20EC1DEF9654A2D092162591C01D26F||1||7707||0||"
            + "0||1002||1373569142000||HTC One||val||4.1.2||0||1.01.20130206.15441^^1000458551||A210171046D86F9F6EE21B66FE9B1441E20EC1DEF9654A2D092162591C01D26F||"
            + "1||7707||0||0||1002||1373569142000||HTC One||val||4.1.2||0||1.01.20130206.15441","1000458551||A210171046D86F9F6EE21B66FE9B1441E20EC1DEF9654A2D092162591C01D26F||1||7707||0||"
                    + "0||1002||1373569142000||HTC One||val||4.1.2||0||1.01.20130206.15441^^1000458551||A210171046D86F9F6EE21B66FE9B1441E20EC1DEF9654A2D092162591C01D26F||"
                    + "1||7707||0||0||1002||1373569142000||HTC One||val||4.1.2||0||1.01.20130206.15441"};    

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
for(String p:str){
        String Recordstore[] = p.split("\\^\\^");
        long len = Recordstore.length;
        long counter = 0;
        StringBuffer finalRecord = new StringBuffer();
        for (String rec : Recordstore) {
            rec = rec.replaceAll("\\|\\|", "|");
            if (counter != len - 1)
                finalRecord.append(rec).append(System.lineSeparator());
            else
                finalRecord.append(rec);
            counter++;
        }
    baos.write(finalRecord.toString().getBytes());
    }
ByteArrayInputStream object = new ByteArrayInputStream(
            baos.toByteArray());
String pr="";
    for(int y = 0 ; y < 1; y++ ) {
         while(( c= object.read())!= -1) {
            pr+=(char)c;
         }
         System.out.println(pr);
         object.reset(); 
      }
```

After converting the string to bytes and rechecking the bytes, I see that the new line character is lost and the string are combined in a single line.
How to be able to preserve the new line character even after the conversion to bytes?

Sample Output is :
adding the new line to the string and printing the string gives:

1000458551|A210171046D86F9F6EE21B66FE9B1441E20EC1DEF9654A2D092162591C01D26F|1|7707|0|0|1002|1373569142000|HTC One|val|4.1.2|0|1.01.20130206.15441
1000458551|A210171046D86F9F6EE21B66FE9B1441E20EC1DEF9654A2D092162591C01D26F|1|7707|0|0|1002|1373569142000|HTC One|val|4.1.2|0|1.01.20130206.15441

After converting it to bytes and printing the string

1000458551|A210171046D86F9F6EE21B66FE9B1441E20EC1DEF9654A2D092162591C01D26F|1|7707|0|0|1002|1373569142000|HTC One|val|4.1.2|0|1.01.20130206.154411000458551|A210171046D86F9F6EE21B66FE9B1441E20EC1DEF9654A2D092162591C01D26F|1|7707|0|0|1002|1373569142000|HTC One|val|4.1.2|0|1.01.20130206.15441

Thanks for the reply in advance

Comment: what newline characters?

Comment: I have appended System.lineSeparator() to the final record. But after I convert it to bytes and recheck the bytes, I dont see the new line.

Comment: do you mean System.getProperty("line.separator"); ?

Comment: yah,from 1.7 the property can directly be added as System.lineSeparator()

Answer (score 0):

Because this line is never executed.

```
finalRecord.append(rec).append(System.lineSeparator());
```

I'm not sure why you split string like this:

```
String Recordstore[] = p.split("\\^\\^");
```

Obviously, the array `Recordstore.length()` will always be 1, since there isn't any `^^` in your original string.

So `counter != len - 1` will always be `false`.

*update:*

I made some changes in this line:

```
baos.write(finalRecord.append(System.lineSeparator()).toString().getBytes());
```

Comment: I have made the changes in my question, apparently i have added wrong string, but still the issue is same.

Comment: @user3218089 I've given a shot on your new string. The problem is you forgot to add newLineSeperater between different `finalRecord`. The newLineSeperater inside `finalRecord` works well.